# Can't see the function "help" using glew in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, sdl-2, glew

The problem is that some functions of glew doesn't have the "help" like the others, here's an example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHcj9.png

I'm using Qt Creator and I'm using SDL library too, all is working fine but the GLEW functions don't.

Comment: Yeh, that's a problem with glew. The thing is, glew only creates macros & function pointers to the actual OpenGL 4+ functions. There is GLLoadGen which can be promising; but Qt also has its own OpenGL context. Take a look at QGLWidget.

Comment: I can't use QGLWidget cause i'm using SDL as my window manager. The question is, why does it works in visual studio and not in QT?

Comment: It's because the IDEs program their intelli sense functionality differently. Visual studio probably has their intelli sense covering function pointers and macros; whereas Qt Creator may not.

Comment: Will search about it, thanks!